# Python asyncio - how to use if function being called has nothing to return

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I have 200 pairs of paths to diff. I wrote a little function that will diff each pair and update a dictionary which itself is one of the arguments to the function. Assume `MY_DIFFER` is some diffing tool I am calling via `subprocess` under the hood.

```
async def do_diff(path1, path2, result):
    result[f"{path1} {path2}"] = MY_DIFFER(path1, path2)
```

As you can see I have nothing to return from this async function. I am just capturing the result in `result`.

I call this function in parallel elsewhere using asyncio like so:

```
path_tuples = [("/path11", "/path12"), ("/path21", "/path22"), ... ]
result = {}
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.gather(
        *(do_diff(path1, path2, result) for path1, path2 in path_tuples)
    )
)
```

Questions:

1. I don't know where to put `await` in the `do_diff` function. But the code seems to work without it as well.
2. I am not sure if the diffs are really happening in parallel, because when I look at the output of `ps -eaf` in another terminal, I see only one instance of the underlying tool I am calling at a time.
3. The speed of execution is same as when I was doing the diffs sequentially

So I am clearly doing something wrong. How can I REALLY do the diffs in parallel?

PS: I am in Python 3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that asyncio doesn't run things *in parallel*, it runs things *concurrently*, using a cooperative multitasking model -- which means that coroutines need to explicitly yield time to other coroutines for them to run. This is what the `await` command does; it says "go run some other coroutines while I'm waiting for something to finish".

If you're never `awaiting` on something, you're not getting concurrent execution.

What you want is for your `do_diff` method to be able to `await` on the execution of your external tool, but you can't do that with just the `subprocess` module. You *can* do that using the [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) method, which arranges to run a synchronous command (e.g., `subprocess.run`) in a separate thread or process and wait asynchronously for the result. That might look something like:

```
async def do_diff(path1, path2, result):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result[f"{path1} {path2}"] = await loop.run_in_executor(None, MY_DIFFER, path1, path2)
```

This will by default run `MY_DIFFER` in a separate thread, although you can utilize a separate process instead by passing an explicit executor as the first argument to `run_in_executor`.

---

Per my comment, solving this with `concurrent.futures` might look something like this:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time


# dummy function that just sleeps for 2 seconds
# replace this with your actual code
def do_diff(path1, path2):
    print(f"diffing path {path1} and {path2}")
    time.sleep(2)
    return path1, path2, "information about diff"


# create 200 path tuples for demonstration purposes
path_tuples = [(f"/path{x}.1", f"/path{x}.2") for x in range(200)]
futures = []

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    for path1, path2 in path_tuples:
        # submit the job to the executor
        futures.append(executor.submit(do_diff, path1, path2))

# read the results
for future in futures:
    print(future.result())
```

Comment: Great answer! Probably you do need a processpoolexecuter here as it seems to be a CPU bound problem

Comment: I am actually trying `multiprocessing.Pool` right now and it seems to be doing the job. It is running 2 diffs at a time (my machine has 2 cores). I am guessing with asyncio I can get more out of it, coz I won't be limited to one process per core, I can have multiple diffs running concurrently (sharing time with each other). Giving this a shot.

Comment: No, I am sorry @shikhanshu there is no magic behind asyncio. If you have just 2 cores, asyncio will have the same limitations. As the name suggests, it mainly shines when it comes to asynchronous IO and not when it comes to parallel processing.

Comment: For what you're doing, I'm not sure that asyncio is going to help all that much. Consider `concurrent.futures` and the [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) instead.

Comment: Yes @larsks I went with `multiprocessing.Pool` with a higher number of `processes` argument. It works exactly as I wanted. Thanks for your answer though. It addresses the questions asked. Marking it as the answer.